# How to attribute authors of assets for my indie game

Tags: assets, copyright, licensing

I am browsing sketchfab.com for assets and some of them are 'CC Attribution' which means you must attribute the author in your work. Where would I put this information in my game? Especially if I am using many assets. Do I have to attribute each author individually or can i just say 'some assets from sketchfab.com' for example?

Comment: Some assets from sketchfab is for the author as helpful as when someone asks about your game and the reply is: someone from country X made it.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[The CC-BY license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0/) requires that you credit the author of the work, not the platform that conveyed it. So yes, when you take lots of assets from lots of different creators, you must credit each of them in the way their individual license conditions demand. Which in the case of the Creative Commons, means with the creators name, the name of the asset, link to the asset and a link to the license. Otherwise you are committing a copyright violation. Which means that the creators of those assets might cause you all kinds of problems. Like sending DMCA takedown notice to the platforms through which you sell your game or even sue you for damages.

General practice for giving credits is the credit screen of your game. Which should, [according to the guidelines by the IGDA](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1-7h1QfjKlY1GWZURWzWubwil035xYT02IlgtINlgPnE/edit), be easily accessible from within your game without having to play the game itself. Yes, game development tradition is to show the credits roll after "beating" the game (whatever that means in the context of the game your are making). And I personally am actually a huge fan of this tradition. But due to the requirement to make credits easily accessible, you usually **also** make them accessible immediately through the start screen or options menu.

My personal approach when dealing with 3rd party assets is to create a text file for each asset I download that contains the credit message as demanded by the license conditions, name it like the asset and store it in the same directory. Not to include those in the final build, but for myself so that I remember what credit I need to give for each asset when I make the credits screen later (which you might even be able to automatize with a script). When you don't keep track of where your assets came from, then you might years later find yourself in the uncomfortable situation that you have to search every single asset site you can think of for hours to again find that !#$%& grass texture you used so you can credit it appropriately.

Comment: @DannyGrogan My recommendation is to follow the IGDA guideline and integrate the credits **into the game itself**. A text file in the game directory is not standard industry practice and usually not easily found by consumers, so it might not satisfy the crediting requirements.

Comment: @DannyGrogan I clarified the answer to make it more clear that the text files with the license conditions are notes for *the development team* to keep track of what must be added to the credits before the game is shipped, not as credit in themselves.

Comment: @DannyGrogan, including the credits in a text file would only suffice if that's also how you credit *yourself*.

Comment: Note also that some Creative Commons licenses *specifically require* you to give attribution on the credits screen, if you have a credits screen. For example, see version 3.0 of [CC-BY-SA](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/legalcode), section 4(b). Apparently this requirement has been removed in version 4.0, but [that license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0/legalcode) still requires you to give attribution in a "reasonable manner," and if you have a credit screen, it may not be reasonable to exclude the attribution from that screen.

Comment: Most games who roll the credits after finishing also give a main-menue option of rolling the credits at any point in time

Answer (score 4):

Exact terms will vary depending on the particular variant of CC license involved.

---

Generally speaking, you will need to include, for ***each*** individual asset:

- a copyright statement; and
- a link to the material; and
- the terms under which use of the asset is granted; and

  - this may entail either inlining the full license text or simply providing a hyperlink to it
- the author's name (may be included in above).

Some versions of the license may require inclusion of the asset's name in addition to or instead of a hyperlink.

Attribution should be reasonably visible (technically "reasonable to the means, medium, and context of use"). In the context of game-dev, this often means including credits accessible from the title screen, launcher, or alongside a readme.

---

You can learn the specifics for each particular CC license at the Creative Commons [website](https://creativecommons.org/licenses#licenses).

The Creative Commons site also provides [examples](https://creativecommons.org/use-remix/attribution/) on how attribution should be given:

> [“Furggelen afterglow”](https://flickr.com/photos/lschlagenhauf/38494602082/) by [Lukas Schlagenhauf](https://flickr.com/photos/lschlagenhauf/) is licensed under [CC BY-ND 2.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nd/2.0/).

> This is an ideal attribution because it includes the:
>
> Title: [“Furggelen afterglow”](https://flickr.com/photos/lschlagenhauf/38494602082/)
>
> Creator: [“Lukas Schlagenhauf“](https://flickr.com/photos/lschlagenhauf/)—with a link to their profile page
>
> Source: [“Furggelen afterglow“](https://flickr.com/photos/lschlagenhauf/38494602082/)—with a link to the original photo on Flickr
>
> License: [“CC BY-ND 2.0”](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/2.0/)—with a link to the license deed

Comment: Clarifying: while including credits in a prominent README.txt, CREDITS.txt, or similar file is acceptable with respect to CC attribution, you'd only really take this route for smaller games without a title screen. If you have a credits page in the game itself, you'd typically include all involved authors/works requiring attribution (not mentioning them here would be disingenuous and bad form, albeit not a violation of license terms).

Comment: As mentioned in my comment on the other answer, in the case of version 3.0 of any Creative Commons license, excluding a CC item from the credits screen really is a license violation, because there's a clause specifically requiring it. This was removed in 4.0, but replaced with a vague "in any reasonable manner" instruction, which could still be construed as meaning "don't leave it out of the credits screen."